# Set jna.library.path from Command line shows error

Tags: java, command-line, cmd, jna

I am new to **Java** and **JNA**. I was trying to access the native interfaces of a third party applications using JNA from Java eclipse. So I was trying to set the *`jna.library.path`* from Command line using the command

```
java -Djna.library.path=<path to your library> MainClass
```

I have given the "path to your library" as the path of the folder where my .dll file and its dependencies are there. for ex: D:Adrin\Library\Dll. 
"MainClass" I have given the name of the class with main() in my application(Jnaexe.java). But an error occurs saying

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Jnaexe.java
```

I have also tried by giving the package name and also the whole path of the Jnaexe.java. Still it does't work. I tried running from the src folder and even the folder where Jnaexe.java file is there(example folder) in command prompt. But the error was same.What I am missing here. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Run with `-Djna.debug_load=true` to see where JNA is looking and why.

Comment: Are you including the `.java` with the class or just putting `Jnaexe` at the end of the initial command?  Have you actually compiled that class and have a Jnaexe.class file located somewere such as a `target` or `build` directory?

Comment: @DanielWiddis I tried both options, with and without .java. Also the compiled class was there in target. I solved the issue by setting the PATH variable instead. The JNA will also look for files in PATH :)